# How to configure a one-to-many/many-to-one relationship between versioned entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was given (therefore I cannot change it) a database with entities that are versioned using a `version` number column.

The entities are *Person*, *Domicile*, *Address*. Each of this entities has a composite primary key made with id and version.

A *Person* can have multiple *Domiciles*, a *Domicile* references an *Address*. An *Address* can be referenced by different *Domiciles*. Therefore we have a one-to-many relationship between a *Person* and its *Domiciles* and there is a many-to-one relationship between *Domicile* and the *Address*.

Each entity reference the other entity only using the id, therefore every entity is versioned indipendently.

Let me give you an example of some tables:

Person

```
|id|version|etc.
|1 |1      |...
|1 |2      |...
```

Domicile

```
|id|version|person_id|address_id|etc...
|2 |1      |1        |3         |...
|2 |2      |1        |3         |...
|3 |1      |1        |4         |...
```

Address

```
|id|version|etc...
|3 |1      |...
|3 |2      |...
|4 |1      |...
```

As you can see each entity reference each other using just the id, and there can be multiple versions of the same entity therefore you can have the same id multiple times.

I would like my model entities to look something like:

```cs
public class Person {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public long Version {get; set;}
  public List<Domicile> Domiciles {get; set;}
}

public class Domicile {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public long Version {get; set;}
  public long AddressId {get; set;}
  public List<Address> AddressVersions {get; set;}
}

public class Address {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public long Version {get; set;}
}
```

Configuring the relationship between a person and its domiciles it's straight-forward:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity => {
  //...
  entity.HasMany(p => p.Domiciles)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Id);
});
```

Now comes the part that I have no clue how to configure: the relationship between a *Domicile* and its *Address* versions. In theory this relation should be a many-to-one because one *Address* is used by multiple *Domiciles*.

I want to have ALL the Address versions on the Domicile so I've declared the property `public List<Address> AddressVersions`, but now I have to configure the navigation property.

If I try to configure the relationship as:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Domicile>(entity => {
  //...
  entity.HasMany(p => p.AddressVersions)
    .WithMany());
});
```

This will not compile because a many-to-many relationship requires a navigation property on both sides.

If I try to model the relationship with a one-to-many configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Domicile>(entity => {
  //...
  entity.HasMany(p => p.AddressVersions)
    .WithOne()
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.AddressId);
});
```

It will not work because I don't have a foreign key on *Address* that refers to *Domicile* given that an *Address* is used by multiple *Domiciles*.

If I go the other way around with the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Domicile>(entity => {
  //...
  entity.HasOne(p => p.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.AddressId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Id);
});
```

Despite this works I get just *one* of the many possibile versions of an *Address*, losing information.

How can I model such relations like between *Address* and *Domicile* and making available on the principal entity all the versions of the related entity ?

EDIT:

Some clarifications on the data:

Every entity has a composite primary key defined as follows:

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (id, version);
```

This composite primary key uniquely identifies a specific record and version.

Every entity references the other entity with a foreign key defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Domicile(
  --etc.
  CONSTRAINT fk_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (id)
);
```

As you can see the foreign key references just a part of the primary key.

In the example table that I provided above I expect that when I select Person with id `1` and version `2` I get 3 domiciles back (id `2` and the two versions `1` and `2` and id `3` with just one version).
Then, for every version of domicile with id `2`, I expect 2 addresses (id `3` with version `1` and `2`) and for the single version of domicile with id `3` I exepect 1 address (id `4` with version `1`)

In code we could write my expectation for *Domicile* with id `2` as:

```cs
Assert.That(domicile.Addresses.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));

Assert.That(domicile.Addresses[0].Id, Is.EqualTo(3));
Assert.That(domicile.Addresses[0].Version, Is.EqualTo(1));

Assert.That(domicile.Addresses[1].Id, Is.EqualTo(3)); //Same address id as before...
Assert.That(domicile.Addresses[0].Version, Is.EqualTo(2)); //...but different version
```

The problem seems to be that the foreign key does not reference unique rows because it uses just a *part* of the primary key, therefore this relationship cannot be modeled (maybe ?) with Entity Framework Core.

Hope this clarifies better what I have to work with and what I want to get.

Comment: First of all the provided setup will not allow you having multiple versions with the same Id cause it will be a primary key and you will get violations when you will try to insert any duplicate Id with different version. You will need composite primary key to handle that with current setup.

Comment: As for many2many relation and _"This will not compile because a many-to-many relationship requires a navigation property on both sides."_ - just add one, what is the problem here? `public List<Domicile> Domicile {get; set;}` on `Address` should work just fine.

Comment: Also personally I would consider moving the versions to separate tables (i.e. `DomicileVerion` and `AddressVersion`).

Comment: @keuleJ this is completely another topic and is not related to the question.

Comment: @GuruStron about the setup and the composite primary key that's exactly what I meant with *Each of this entities has a composite primary key made with id and version.* Unfortunately I cannot make changes to the schema, so no new separate tables for the versions. About the many to many suggestion it would not work anyway because I do not have a join table between the two entities.

Comment: @Gwinn your code does not have set up for a composite key. Please add the correct code.

Comment: @Gwinn _"About the many to many suggestion it would not work anyway because I do not have a join table between the two entities."_ - then create one (because it seems to be needed to correctly model the relation, with possibly additional constraint that domicile should be connected to only one address).  And of course you will need to use full composite primary key (or any unique one) for the relations. It is not EF set up problem, it is what is usually required by relational databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is what you want cannot be done with built-in functionality.  Perhaps third party extensions/tools could help.

`Id` is not unique for any of your three entities so you cannot have a many-to-one or one-to-many relationship between them using only an `Id` property as the principal key (since the principal key must uniquely identify the related record).

Options:

1. manually join these entities and project the results
2. create DB views (if allowed) to provide the junction entities that EF could use for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that you don't need any 3rd party libraries to have composite primary keys in EF.

Comment: @GuruStron I don't think the anwer is suggesting to use 3rd parties for composite keys. The problem is that entities are in relationship with each other with just a PART of their composite primary key so you cannot uniquely indetify records

Comment: @Gwinn _"Perhaps third party extensions/tools could help."_

Comment: @GuruStron you are correct, but as Gwinn pointed out, you seemed to have misunderstood the point.  The pseudo "foreign keys" don't reference a candidate key so there can be no relationship modeled in EF as is.  Custom extensions for EF could implement a way to configure the many to many relationships using part of a composite candidate key.  I don't know of any, but they may exist.